# Is it possible to open embedded tweets in a new tab?

Tags: twitter

Since a while I have seen that some tweets are "embedded" within others. A recent example from my twitter feed:

[image]

If I want to interact with the embedded tweet, I have to click on it. Until I do, I cannot even select the text.

Unfortunately, clicking does not open the tweet in a new tab of my browser, meaning that when I'll go back to the feed I will have to scroll all the way back to where I was.

I have tried clicking with the middle mouse button, but it does not appear to work.
My current solution is to open the "embedder" tweet in a new tab (middle click on the time of the post) and then click on the embedded tweet.

Is there a less cumbersome alternative? (maybe some twitter option I missed?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reading from the webapp then you'll need to hold down either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (on Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd> (if you're on Mac) before clicking the embedded/replied-to tweet.

That will open it up into a new tab (or new window depending on your browser settings).

Comment: I never knew that Ctrl was a universal Windows key for "New Tab", thanks! I tested this and it works.